# objectdatasource search help

Tags: asp.net

i have my ObjectDataSource1 setup to use with my GridView. If I want to setup a Search text box for the GridView will I need to create a new ObjectDataSource2 to tie it to the Search textbox?

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    TypeName="ShelterExpress.ShelterData"
    DataObjectTypeName="ShelterExpress.Shelter" 
    InsertMethod="InsertShelter" 
    UpdateMethod="UpdateShelter"
    DeleteMethod="DeleteShelter" 
    SelectMethod="GetShelters" 
OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="shelterId" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Rod?  Have the same problem and am wondering if there is a way to do this without going the manual route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to setup select parameters like you've done for delete. You'll use control parameters.

```
<SelectParameters>
                   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="text" Direction="input" Name="filterField" type="string"/>
                </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: When the page first loads, all records are loaded into the gridview by ObjectDataSource1. What has to happen after a search criteria is entered and the search button is pressed?